# InvalidAttributeValException running code

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I am getting a syntax error in my code with Jython. Can anyone say what's wrong in the syntax? I am new to this language, don't have much of an idea.

Error Message :

`WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "namespace.jy"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidAttributeValException: ADMG0012E: The attribute value for attribute integration/endpoint/account is not valid.`

---

My Code:

```
import sys

nodeName =sys.argv[0]
serverName =sys.argv[1]
profilePath=sys.argv[2]
machineName=sys.argv[3]



#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Main program
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
createNamespaceBinding(nodeName,serverName,profilePath,machineName)
```

I have added call to `setJVMSystemProperties()`, so it will ignore `'/'` in the name attribute, but am still facing the problem.

Comment: Can some please help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: @mzjn please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. Sorry.

Comment: please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

It worked for  after adding this property file com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.validateNames  = false    and then stopping and starting the server and then try to run jython script for namespace binding

Comment: If the problem is solved, mark the answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).